# OpenFileDialog issue in FSI

Tags: winforms, f#, f#-interactive

Simple question:

In F# Interactive, this does not work (it shows no dialog):

```
open System.Windows.Forms
let dlg = new OpenFileDialog()
let res = dlg.ShowDialog()
```

This code does work, after I first do a simple MessageBox:

```
open System.Windows.Forms
MessageBox.Show("Now it works!")
let dlg = new OpenFileDialog()
let res = dlg.ShowDialog()
```

This code also works, after first showing a Form:

```
open System.Windows.Forms
let frm = new Form()
frm.Show()
let dlg = new OpenFileDialog()
let res = dlg.ShowDialog()
```

This code however does not show any forms, not even the Messagebox:

```
open System.Windows.Forms
let dlg = new OpenFileDialog()
let res = dlg.ShowDialog()
MessageBox.Show("Now it does not work...")
```

It seems the OpenFileDIalog blocks on something, if it does not have some other form warm/ load something first, no idea what.

Any ideas what would make the OpenFileDialog work straight away?

Using Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.40219.1

Thanks, GJ

Comment: Works fine for me in 3.0 and 3.1 FSI, perhaps an old bug.

Comment: Just tried it on VS2012/FSI 11.0.60610.1 (was using 2010 because of compatability) but I get the exact same behaviour as in 2010..

Comment: Works for me on 11.0.60610.1.  Note that the windows pop up *behind* the VS UI, which is not ideal, but they are there.

Comment: You're right. The OpenFileDialog was there, but behind VS. When I minimlize VS I see it. The difference is that when I open a Form or MEssageBox first, then the OpenFileDialog gets an Icon on the taskbar, else it doesn't. Can't mark a comment as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows are there, they just appear *behind* the Visual Studio UI, so it's easy not to notice them.  I'm not sure why they do not appear in the foreground.

A quick test in FSI from the command line (i.e. not the hosted VS one) indicates the windows come to the foreground in this case.